# How to add time with date in woo commerce product sale option?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

In woocommerce when I add **sale price dates** for start & end the sale there is an option for a date only, we can not set time in this section (Image attached Please have a look)
[image]

and time is set by the current time zone used.

When I looked in tabel wp_postmeta, I found after creating the sale,  two meta keys ***_sale_price_dates_from & _sale_price_dates_to*** for that product created & values for that keys are Unix Timestamp. These values are also storing time. But that time is set by the current time zone enabled in WordPress.For start date, this time is always 00:00:00 and for the end date, it is always 23:59:59

***Image for _sale_price_dates_from* & *_sale_price_dates_to***

[image: Image of wp_postmeta table]

***What I am trying***  - I want to enable time in the calendar so that I can create the sale for a small time duration. I don't want to use any plugin for this. For example, I want to add sales for a product only for 2 hrs.

How can I add/enable time in this JS-based calendar?

Any Advice?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm currently struggling with the exact same issue